# Draw on PNG without System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, png, gdi+

For debugging purposes, I'd like to draw on an image in my c# app (I have lots of tiles and I'd like to know which one is which).  However, when trying to do it via System.Drawing.Graphics, I run into the fact that the image I'm trying to draw on is a GIF (which I don't have any choice over).  Is there another way to draw on images in c#/.NET without using the classes in System.Drawing?

Comment: 1) Why can't you use `System.Drawing`? 2) Are you trying to draw PNG or GIF?

Comment: I'm trying to draw on a PNG, and it's complaining about it using indexed color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this isn't the question you asked, but I'm guessing the reason you're not able to draw on the Bitmap from your GIF is that the pixel format is indexed. If so, that's easy to work around by making a copy with a non-indexed format using the [Bitmap.Clone method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx). Just give it the full bitmap size and PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb.

I don't know any other standard drawing API's in .NET that are convenient for this purpose.